# Q: How to store the results of a calculation into a hidden field

Tags: php, gravity-forms-plugin

We have a gravity form in 4 parts.

```
1. Input an Australian postcode
2. Select swimming pool dimensions
3. Select accessories
4. Show quotation, prompt for contact details.
```

In functions.php we have defined a few global symbols. `$PostCode` is set to the value of the postcode value that is entered on page 1. Once `$PostCode` is > 0 we include a php file. This file contains a large array of freight charges indexed by the postcode. The postcode-specific charges are transferred to hidden fields on page 2 of the form and are used for later calculations.

Along with the freight charges is a formula. This formula is evaluated using data from the hidden fields on page 2 and also from a number field on page 2 that calculates the pool area from entry fields of length and width.

The result of the evaluation of the formula should be entered into a field on page 3 for use in other calculations. It is at this point that a problem is encountered, namely that the receiving hidden field is not updated.

Code:

```
// global symbols
$Formula1 = '';
$TNTFreightPrices = array();
$FieldNumberContent = array();
$PostCode = '';
$Formula1Result = 0;

add_filter('gform_field_input_11', 'update_hidden', 10, 5);
function update_hidden($input, $field, $value, $lead_id, $form_id)
{
    global $TNTFreightPrices, $FieldNumberContent, $Formula1, $PostCode, $Formula1Result;

    $pgno = $field['pageNumber'];

    $PostCode = rgpost("input_3");

    if (!empty($PostCode)) {
        $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/uploads/tntfreightprices/TNTFreightPrices.php';
        $tmp = include_once $path;
        if (gettype($tmp) == "array") {
            $TNTFreightPrices = $tmp['postcodes'];
            $Formula1 = $tmp['Formula1'];
            $f = $form_id;
            $BasicChrg = $TNTFreightPrices[$PostCode]['BasicChrg'];
            $KgChrg = $TNTFreightPrices[$PostCode]['KgChrg'];
            $MinChrg = $TNTFreightPrices[$PostCode]['MinChrg'];
            $RemotAreaChrg = $TNTFreightPrices[$PostCode]['RemotAreaChrg'];
            $ResidChrg = $TNTFreightPrices[$PostCode]['ResidChrg'];
            $_0to15Chrg = $TNTFreightPrices[$PostCode]['0to15Chrg'];
            $_15to199Chrg = $TNTFreightPrices[$PostCode]['15to199Chrg'];
            $_200to299Chrg = $TNTFreightPrices[$PostCode]['200to299Chrg'];
            $_300to399Chrg = $TNTFreightPrices[$PostCode]['300to399Chrg'];
            $_400to499Chrg = $TNTFreightPrices[$PostCode]['400to499Chrg'];
            $_500to599Chrg = $TNTFreightPrices[$PostCode]['500to599Chrg'];
            $_600plusChrg = $TNTFreightPrices[$PostCode]['600plusChrg'];
            $FuelSurchrg = $TNTFreightPrices[$PostCode]['FuelSurchrg'];

            $FieldNumberContent = array(
                '85' => Content_tag(
                    "input", "",
                    array(
                        "id" => "input_{$f}_85",
                        "class" => "gform_hidden",
                        "name" => "input_85",
                        "aria-invalid" => "false",
                        "value" => "$BasicChrg",
                        "type" => "hidden")
                ),
            // ...
```

The `Content_tag` function is not shown. It generates HTML to set the value of the hidden fields on page 2. An example of its output is

```
input id="input_11_85" class="gform_hidden" name="input_85" aria-invalid="false" value="9.33" type="hidden">
```

These values are stored in the `$FieldNumberContent` array and are returned to the caller depending on the field_id, viz

```
$fid = $field['id'];
if (array_key_exists($fid, $FieldNumberContent)) {
    $input = $FieldNumberContent[$fid];
}
```

The `update_hidden` function ends with

```
    return $input;
}
```

The next block of code takes the values of the hidden fields on page 2 and the result of the area calculation, also on page 2 and replaces the matching values in the formula stored in `$Formula1`, finally eval'ing the string and storing its result in the global `$Formula1Result`.

```
add_filter('gform_field_value', 'populate_fields_into_formula1', 10, 3);
function populate_fields_into_formula1( $value, $field, $name ) 
{    
    global $Formula1, $PostCode, $TNTFreightPrices, $Formula1Result;
    if (array_key_exists($PostCode, $TNTFreightPrices) ) {
        $fid = $field['id'];
        if (strpos($Formula1, "[") !== false) {
            $sym = "[{$field['label']}]";
            $val = rgpost("input_{$fid}");
            $Formula1 = str_replace($sym, $val, $Formula1);
        } else {
            $f1 = "return {$Formula1};";
            $f1 = str_replace(",", "", $f1);
            $Formula1Result = eval($f1);
        }
    }
    return $value;
}
```

An example formula is

```
[AreaCalculator]/2 * [KgChrg] >= [MinChrg] ? [AreaCalculator]/2 * [KgChrg] : [MinChrg]
```

Finally here's the code that is supposed to updating the field hidden field on page 3. We clicked the checkbox allowing the field to be updated dynamically and gave the parameter name as `formula1result`.

```
add_filter('gform_field_value_formula1result', 'populate_formula1result', 10, 3);
function populate_formula1result($value, $field, $name) 
{

    global $Formula1Result;
    if ($Formula1Result > 0) {
        $value = $Formula1Result;
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Now I confess up front that I am not a particularly adept PHP programmer. Perhaps there is a better way of doing all this, and believe me I am all ears. 
But I've been metaphorically hitting my head against this for a day or more. Everything else appears to be working. It's only this that's not Why?

Comment: Wow you're a really old member of the site... ID 426

Comment: Yep, been around a while. Have sacrificed my rep a few times to get answers. I'm quite indebted to S/O, actually. This forum has solved some very knotty problems for me over the years. It was amazing  watching Mr Skeet rocket up the charts. My climb has been more pedestrian.